# How enable ellipsis when calling Python doctest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ellipsis, doctest

In Python (3.3.2) doctest, ellipsis (`...`) can match any string. So, for the code below

```
def foo():
    """
    >>> foo()
    hello ...
    """
    print("hello world")
```

when running doctest it shouldn't raise any error. But

```
$ python -m doctest foo.py 
**********************************************************************
File "./foo.py", line 3, in foo.foo
Failed example:
    foo()
Expected:
    hello ...
Got:
    hello world
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   1 in foo.foo
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

What I must do to enable the ellipis? As far as I can tell it is disable by default.

I know that add `# doctest: +ELLIPSIS`, as in the code below, solve it, but I like to enable ellipsis for all tests.

```
def foo():
    """
    >>> foo() # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    hello ...
    """
    print("hello world")
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can pass in `optionflags` to the [`testmod`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#doctest.testmod) method, but this requires you to run the module itself instead of the `doctest` module:

```
def foo():
    """
    >>> foo()
    hello ...
    """
    print("hello world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True, optionflags=doctest.ELLIPSIS)
```

Output:

```
$ python foo.py
Trying:
    foo()
Expecting:
    hello ...
ok
1 items had no tests:
    __main__
1 items passed all tests:
   1 tests in __main__.foo
1 tests in 2 items.
1 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

Answer (score 9):

You can enable options for an individual example like this:

```
'''
>>> 'foobarbaz' # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
'foo...baz'
'''
```

The [`doctest` directives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#doctest-directives) documentation is hard to understand because the actual directives seem to be parsed away and aren't visible. There is an [open bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue36675) for this. In the meantime you can view the [raw documentation source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/master/Doc/library/doctest.rst) instead.

Comment: This answer is a life saver since it doesn't change global behaviour and doesn't need additional setup code in your doctest call.

Answer (score 6):

Since Python 3.4, you can pass the option with the `-o` flag:

```
$ python -m doctest -o=ELLIPSIS foo.py
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#option-flags